# Match list of words all uppercase or all lowercase regex

Tags: regex

I'm using CodeMirror [to write a simple mode](https://codemirror.net/demo/simplemode.html) (not sure what kind of regex they use), and was wondering if I had a list of words that I wanted to match, like `aaa`, `bbb`, and `ccc` I could do it with `/aaa|bbb|ccc/`, and it would match the lowercase versions. But how would I get it to match only ALL lowercase and ALL uppercase? The equivalent of `/aaa|AAA|bbb|BBB|ccc|CCC/`

Comment: It would be possible in some flavors, but not in Javascript, I don't think, other than your original `/aaa|AAA|bbb|BBB|ccc|CCC/` (assuming the actual words have different characters)

Comment: @CertainPerformance could you give any pointers to what could work in other flavors?

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed I think he is referring in general, as JS regex implementation in my opinion is very minimal compared to .NET and I suppose Java. For example, in .NET with the help of `Conditional Matching` and `Character Category`, the OP question can be answered. However, not sure of JavaScript.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed For example, `^(?=[A-Z]+$|[a-z]+$)(?i:aaa|bbb|ccc)` using `(?i` to enable the `i` flag only inside the alternated word group https://regex101.com/r/YlLayT/2

Comment: @CertainPerformance Oh, the `(?i` is new to me. This is very useful, thanks a lot!.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match words like `AaA` or `aAA`, you're looking for the case-insensitive modifier `i`:

```
/aaa|bbb|ccc/i
```

This can be seen working **[here](https://regex101.com/r/POSbm7/1/)**.

If you only want to match groups of uppercase and lowercase characters, you'll need a more complex regex like:

```
/^[a-z]+$|^[A-Z]+$/g
```

The two groups `a-z` and `A-Z` handle lowercase and uppercase characters, both constrained by the start `(^`) and end `$` of the string. Because you want either all uppercase or all lowercase characters , you'll want to also make use of a pipe (`|`) denoting an `OR`.

This can be seen in working **[here](https://regex101.com/r/YlLayT/1/)**.

Comment: OP is looking to match *all lowercase* or *all uppercase*. Your code will match, eg, `'aAa'`.

Comment: but i don't want to match words like `aaA` or `bBB` where they're not ALL uppercase or ALL lowercase

Comment: OP wants a particular *list of words* to match, not *any combination* of characters that are all uppercase or all lowercase.

Comment: So just put the target lowercase word in `[a-z]` and the uppercase word in `[A-Z]`, making sure to leave off the `i` flag? I find it ironic that many high-ranking people on SO are quick to downvote but not offer solutions of their own.

Comment: OP doesn't have some words required to be lowercase and some required to be uppercase, he wants *all* of them to be lowercase or uppercase - as he says, the equivalent of `/aaa|AAA|bbb|BBB|ccc|CCC/`. I didn't downvote, but I don't think it's possible to improve on his example wordy regex in the question, given that the environment is JS - see comments on the question.

Comment: The question is so poor in asking that I'd never post an answer for it. I cast you an upvote, however.

Comment: wait @revo what do you mean it is "poor in asking"? How can I improve the question?

Answer (score 0):

This pattern does it if I'm not wrong:

```
^([A-Z][A-Z]*|[a-z][a-z]*)$
```

Explanation, either:

- An uppercase letter followed by all uppercases
- An lowercase letter followed by all lowercases

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution using Java.  The regex should be valid for most regex engines.

```
String[] words = {"HELLO","goodbye", "Java", "aaaAAA"};
```

- The character classes `[]` have one or more characters of the required case.
- I am also using word boundaries so `AAAaaa` won't match both `AAA` and `aaa` separately.  But that also depends on how you apply the regex.

```
String regex = "\\b[A-Z]+\\b|\\b[a-z]+\\b";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(wordString);
```

`String.matches` matches the complete string.

```
for (String word : words) {
    System.out.printf("%-10s ->  %s%n", word,
            word.matches(regex) ? "Match!" : "No Match!");
}
```

prints

```
HELLO      ->  Match!
goodbye    ->  Match!
Java       ->  No Match!
aaaAAA     ->  No Match!
```

Here is an example where the word boundaries make a difference.  Without them, `J`, `ava`, `aaa`, and `AAA` would match.

```
String wordString = "HELLO goodbye Java  aaaAAA";
```

`Marcher.find()` returns true if a match is found.  It is accessed vi `Matcher.group()`

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(wordString);
while(m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

prints

```
HELLO
goodbye
```